# Sheets Discovery API fails for preflight request

Tags: angularjs, cors, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Discovery API to support Google OAuth in my AngularJS project. I use [this URL](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis), and then the corresponding `discoveryRestUrl` to get the API scopes.

Everything works fine, until I try the above with Google Sheets' `discoveryRestUrl` i.e. https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4.

I use Angular's `$http` service to fire a `GET` requests for fetching API specific info. In my browser console, I see two requests being generated -- One is with `OPTIONS` method (preflight), second is with `GET` method (which fetches the JSON data).

For Sheets, I get the following error in my browser's console when preflight request is made.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I do not see such issue with other APIs. I tried to fire the same URL with my browser, and cURL, but they just work fine.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I have found that including token headers in the request for some API discovery resources causes the server to validate the scope and fail to serve the request if the scopes are not included. This can be frustrating when you are trying to use the discovery spec to determine the required scopes ;^)

The solution is to either include a required scope if you are doing OAUTH'd requests or to simply make the request without the AUTH headers which should work for most APIs except for a small count of those that are restricted and not available for general consumption anyway.